# Keeping Deities/God photos in everywhere in home

Tags: gods, practice

Some orthodox Hindu families (*Middle class*) keep deities photos every place in their home.

1. Some keep partially divided in the kitchen
2. Some keep in the hall itself
3. Bed room is an optional if someone wants to see the first sight everyday.

Is this right? Any scriptures say about this in Hinduism. (If there is no separate pooja room.)

Comment: I dont think you will find rules like that. Its up to the person if he likes photos in all rooms.

Comment: God is not resided only in separate puja room. God is everywhere, then we can keep their photos everywhere :)

Comment: Sorry to say this @Rishabh: We couldn't keep photos every rooms.

Comment: put reminders of God everywhere.........

Comment: Yes usually it is ideal if a separate Puja room can be formed. Otherwise the deities shd be kept in a covered place (small Mandir or a wooden box). While worshiping the cover is removed during other times it is kept covered. This is the practice I hv noticed being followed becoz many families may not hv a separate place for Puja. But finding scriptural instructions may be hard to do here. @ssr1012

Comment: @ssr1012 _"We couldn't keep photos every rooms."_  If you are sure about this then what basis you have for your surety? I mean, this faith of your is based on what information? Have you heard somewhere that we shouldn't keep photos in every room? But since God is sarvyapi(everywhere) then how we can mark boundaries (by limiting him on one room) for sarvyapi Parmeshvar? Is this even possible?

Comment: @Rishabh: what is source or references on your comments. Nothing Just like _god is everywhere_. Yes. You are very very right. I am accepted. **There is no logic in your comments since I am not asking where is god.** Sorry to say this once again we can't kept the photos in hall or kitchen in case if the middle age woman having a periods time. Are you accepted this? Also we cant kept the photos in entrance of rest room right? Ok lets go with your statement _Sarvyapi_ then why the temples are built? *Parmeshvar* is everywhere then why the people going to see kailash in the earth.

Comment: @Rickross: Once again I registered in my mind *God is everywhere*. Thanks. Ok then as per your indirect answer I shall take this as **photos are no needed at home. Right?** Since god is everywhere. We should do pooja's, prayers, chanting mantras during cooking, bathing, dressing etc...

Comment: God is everywhere is only a belief/theory/concept.. Such advises do not mean anything practically. Do we see God being present everywhere? NO right? So, some basic rules are to be maintained while keeping images of Gods in house other than Puja place. For e.g one shd not keep them in the bedroom where husband and wife sleeps (for obvious reasons).. For similar reasons one shd not keep them in toilets either.. @ssr1012

Comment: @rickross if you find scriptual references about coverings please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Don'ts:
One must refrain from keeping brahmachari deties like Sri Hanumanji, Shani Maharaj, etc at home. If one keeping these deties/ idols should himself practice Brahmacharya and live a Sattvic life as a Brahmin. Never chant Hanuman/Shani chalisa at home, instead use local temple space to chant and get wishes fulfilled. Women should never touch idols of Brahmachari deties even at temples, it's a common sense in itself after all, else negative reactions observed in life automatically.

Also, one should avoid keeping Jyotirlingam if one can't duly worship daily, keep a constant water Dhara flowing over it.

It's best to worship and spend money to keep worshipping them in the temples instead, and get blessings instead of wrath.
Similarly, there are many other God/Goddess one must always be careful if out of child like mindset one brings them home and later due to grihast duties/forgetfulness doesn't worship them with proper rites and rituals, then it might invoke spiritual reactions from those deties.

One can ask for forgiveness and then, dutifully place deties/idols in flowing water to further prevent damage to family, avoid indulging in bad spiritual practices.

Do's: 
Daily worship of kuldevta,kuldevi, Ganpati is a boon in itself to Grihasts leading to the heavens easily, along with material gains fulfilled.

One can as per will perform occasional VRATA/Pooja of other deties on specific days but only with full commitment and respectfully, obeying all rites as per the scriptures/ Pooja rituals of that particular deity