# Can I keep a small murti of lord hanuman in my room

Tags: hanuman, idols

I have heard that as the size of murti grows it attracts more divine power and requires more Pooja. Hence one should not keep a large murti at home but how about small metal one around 3-4 inch. Can I keep a small idol?

Comment: Related : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29789/15702

Comment: Please note that that a true devotee does not need an idol. This is for the lowest of devotees! The best devotee only needs his mind.

Comment: @wikash_ Thinking ourselves greater devotee than other is something called ego. The devotee who has ego of devotion, that devotee can never be called true devotee :)

Comment: @Rishabh I did not make this up. This is scriptually valid. There is a ranking.

Comment: @wikash_ Okay, got your point. Means, we should rely on our thoughts and imagination rather than physical objects to get more close to Lord. We should think about lord in our thoughts on daily basis. I hope I understand it right :)

Comment: @Rishabh yes exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the size, please focus on the arrangement of deities. There is nothing wrong in keeping a large idol of Hanumanji if you have a big house!

Couple of sites for your reference:

- https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/arrange-deities-home-temple
- https://www.quora.com/Should-we-keep-Gods-small-murthis-statues-within-a-bowl-of-rice-in-pooja-room

Comment: Welcome! Refer [What kind of references are valid in answers? Are modern works allowed?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/3500) for valid sources and references.